# script.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTime' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I am doing a music player on js and i need to do a slider so the user can navigate in the audio

Here is my code:

```js
function slider_container() {
  const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  const time = audio.currentTime;
  const time_max = audio.duration;

  document.getElementById('current_time').innerHTML = "" + time_max + "";
}
slider_container();
```

```html
<div class="slider_container">
  <div class="current-time" id="current_time">00:00</div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="seek_slider" onchange="seekTo()">
  <div class="total-duration">00:00</div>
</div>

<audio src="Audio/free.mp3" id="audio" autoplay="autoplay">

        </audio>
```

Comment: as I see your id "audio" has no curentTime value.
You have to update audio = document.getElementById('current_time');

Comment: currentTime seems to be an attribute that is part of the audio API

Comment: I get error on the missing seekTo function

Comment: Have you got your Javascript loading before your HTML? If so the element with id audio will not exist at the time you call slider_container. Put the JS at the end and see what happens.

Comment: Why you are trying to create a custom seek bar? Because the audio player has seek control by default. you need to add `controls` attribute

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need!

```js
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var slider =  document.getElementById('slider');



function getTime(seconds){
  var date = new Date(seconds * 1000);
  var hh = date.getUTCHours();
  var mm = date.getUTCMinutes();
  var ss = date.getSeconds();
  if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
  if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}
  if (ss < 10) {ss = "0"+ss;} 
  var t = hh+":"+mm+":"+ss;
  return t;
}



function seekTo(){
  audio.currentTime = slider.value/100 * audio.duration;
}

function audioLoad(){
  document.getElementById('duration').innerText = getTime(audio.duration);
}

function reset(){
  audio.currentTime = 0;
}

function play(){
  audio.play();
}

function pause(){
  audio.pause();
}

setInterval(function(){
  audioLoad();
  document.getElementById('current_time').innerText = getTime(audio.currentTime);
  slider.value = audio.currentTime/audio.duration * 100;
}, 500);
```

```html
<div class="slider_container">
  <div class="current-time" id="current_time">00:00</div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" id="slider" class="seek_slider" onchange="seekTo()">
  <div id = "duration" class="total-duration">00:00</div>
</div>
<button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
<audio audioLoad src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3" id="audio" autoplay="autoplay">

        </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is happening because you already executed the `slider_container()` method before your HTML document is fully loaded.

So either you have to place your script at the bottom lines of HTML document or you have to use [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) to correctly execute your code.

Also it seems to me you are not updating each time the music is being playing.

Thanks to [Jaysmito Mukherjee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577103/12268460) answer on this question.

I have taken some parts of his code and written pure JS based event handling of custom music player bar. I have merged two buttons "Play" and "Pause" to one button.

Here I have used [Audio Ontimeupdate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) to update the time every time music is played.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
        const current_time = document.getElementById('current_time');
        const total_duration = document.getElementById('total-duration');
        const seek_slider = document.getElementById('seek_slider');
        const play_pause_button = document.getElementById('play_pause');
        const reset_button = document.getElementById('reset');

        var time,time_max;

        function getTime(seconds){
            var date = new Date(seconds * 1000);
            var hh = date.getUTCHours();
            var mm = date.getUTCMinutes();
            var ss = date.getSeconds();
            if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
            if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}
            if (ss < 10) {ss = "0"+ss;} 
            var t = hh+":"+mm+":"+ss;
            return t;
        }

        // Assign an ontimeupdate event to the <video> element, and execute a function if the current playback position has changed
        audio.ontimeupdate = function() { 
            slider_container();
            slider_mover();
        };

        play_pause_button.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
            if(play_pause_button.innerHTML=='Play'){
                audio.play();
                play_pause_button.innerHTML="Pause";
            }else if(play_pause_button.innerHTML=='Pause'){
                audio.pause();
                play_pause_button.innerHTML='Play';
            }
        });

        reset_button.addEventListener('click', function(){ audio.currentTime = 0; });

        function update_time(){
            time = audio.currentTime;
            time_max = audio.duration;
        }

        function slider_container() {
            update_time();
            current_time.innerHTML = getTime(time);
            total_duration.innerHTML = getTime(time_max);
        }

        function slider_mover(){
            update_time();
            var percentage_num = (time/time_max)*100;

            seek_slider.value = percentage_num;
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="slider_container">
  <div class="current-time" id="current_time">00:00</div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="seek_slider" id="seek_slider">
  <div class="total-duration" id="total-duration">00:00</div>
</div>

<button id="play_pause">Play</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<audio src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3"" id="audio" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
```